# How do I calculate the potentiometer value for the controlling of Alpha angle of a phase control IC?

Tags: power-electronics, rectifier, triac, thyristor, scr

The datasheet suggests to use a 10Kohm pot to control the Alpha angle, however no matter how much I try I can't control it. I used 1Mohm pot instead and now I can control it more, but still with very small range.
I reach the actual movement range while trying with an extremely fine rotating to get it move, then when I pass a certain point I completely lose the triggering pulses. I also tried with 500Kohm pot but the movement range was even less..

P.S I am using single turn potentiometer. And TCA785 phase control IC.

[image]

[Datasheet](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1836360.pdf)

Comment: What does the datasheet say about V11?

Comment: "If the ramp voltage V10 exceeds the control voltage V11 (triggering angle ϕ), a signal is processed to the logic. Dependent on the magnitude of the control voltage V11, the triggering angle ϕ can be shifted within a phase angle of 0˚".. 
I read the whole datasheet and I can't figure out what am I missing..

Comment: For voltage levels, it shouldn't matter, 10k or 1Meg pot.  Link the datasheet in the OP so others can look at it.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by *"I can't control it"* and *"I can control it more"*.

Comment: with the 10k pot I rotate it all the way around and I can't move the pulse position. With the 1M pot I can actually move it but It is not smoothly and I lose the pulse say at 45 degrees or even less.

Answer (score 1):

From the datasheet on page 7 you have a formula for the current into that 47nF cap C5:
[image: charge current]

(K is apparently 1.1±20%)

Since the voltage on the cap is the integral of the current multiplied by 1/C, I get a ramp rate of 965V/s, which seems like a lot, but you haven't mentioned your supply voltage or input frequency. Compounding this is that the minimum voltage on that cap is ~200mV and the maximum is Vs-2V, you have a smaller range to do that ramping in.
The given design is capable of a minimum of ~30Hz @18V supply, or a minimum of ~80Hz with an 8V supply. I recommend you use an oscilloscope to probe the voltage at C5 and "alpha" to get an understanding of what's actually happening in your implementation.

Since your potentiometer is connected across the supply rails note that the bottom .2V and the top 2V worth (100*(1-2.2/Vsupply in percent) are dead zone; with an 8V supply that's a full quarter of the range. Adding series resistors to the supply and ground connections of the pot will reduce the deadband:
[image: less range more control]

Comment: I appreciate it Bryan, yes I am using 8V supply and the AC frequency is 50Hz... I will try to add these resistors and come back with an update ..

Comment: Note that at 8V and 50Hz your capacitor will saturate before the half cycle is complete, you wont be able to trigger later angles. I recommend increasing the value of C5 or R9, either 100nf or 130kohm will get you full range.